# How to choose an operator when making a simple calculator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, calculator

I'm making a simple calculator in C++, but I'm having trouble choosing an operator, I wonder who can help me?
I'm using this code:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string operation = "";
cout << "enter operation:";
if(operation = "/"){
 int x;
 cin >> x;
 int y;
 cin >> y;
 int sum = x / y;
 }
 if(operation = "+"){
 int x;
 cin >> x;
 int y;
 cin >> y;
 int sum = x + y;
 }
 if(operation = "*"){
 int x;
 cin >> x;
 int y;
 cin >> y;
 int sum = x * y;
 }
 if(operation = "-"){
   int x;
   cin >> x;
   int y;
   cin >> y;
   int sum = x - y;
     }
   }
```

I dont know more programming. Who can help me?

Comment: Please, step-wise debug `if(operation = "/")`. Spoiler: `=` ... assignment vs. `==` ... equal compare.

Comment: Reminder: One `=` for assignment, two `==` for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a line to read in the operation the user enters. After the line `cout << "enter operation:";`, you probably need `cin >> operation`.

A couple of other code improvements worth doing:

- consider moving setting X and y outside the if statements, as you repeat the same code 4 times
- consider using a switch statement rather than 4 if statements, as currently it will perform all 4 checks every time
- as others have said, use `==` rather than `=`

Comment: Ok.  Thank you I solved the problem.

Comment: I have already realized that the cin >> operation code is forgotten. But though thanks

Comment: No worries, glad you fixed it!